# wp_nav_menu parent in submenu

Tags: menus, navigation, sub-menu

I'm using wp_nav_menu() to display a multilevel menu.

How can I add a parent link as a first item to the submenu?

```
- Item 1
 -- Item 1 (parent)
 -- Item 1.1
 -- Item 1.2
 -- Item 1.3
- Item 2
- Item 3
 -- Item 3 (parent)
 -- Item 3.1
 -- Item 3.2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add parent element's title to nav menu's child?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/289458/how-to-add-parent-elements-title-to-nav-menus-child) Seems to be a similar question, albeit a title instead of a link, but changing the `<h3>` tag to an `<a>` tag should do the trick.